# Can I use a different Eclipse Formatter Profile for on-open and on-save?

Tags: eclipse

I love the Eclipse feature that allows the Formatter Profile to be applied on save, but what if my preferred bracing style differs from the project "standard"? Is there a way to apply one Formatter Profile when I open a file, and another when I save it?

I suppose there would be complications when debugging, but maybe there's some brilliant Eclipse Plugin developer that has solved this problem. I can hope, right?

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge for Java sources.
Especially since, at the first saved modification, the bracing style would then revert to the second Formatter profile, hence modifying the reading experience.
Plus that would required a mandatory recompilation on project/source opening, for the debug informations to be correctly stored.

The only kind of formatting I know about are for *non-compiled* files, like xml ones.

OxygenXml has [such a setting in place](http://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/ug-editor/topics/preferences-editor-format.html), with [PrettyPrint](http://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/ug-editor/topics/formatting-and-indenting-xml-documents.html).

[image: http://www.oxygenxml.com/img/prettyPrint.gif]

> Format and indent the document on open
>
> When checked, the Format and indent the document on open operation will format and indent the document before opening it in the editor panel.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK True. I have restored the link and picture.